# ASP.NET - How to get selectedvalues from dynamicallyproduced dropdownlists inside Repeater Control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Hi have the following vb code in ASP.NET:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL_SRC_DEV_HIERACHY">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <p class="input_title">Hierachy:
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Hierarchy_SKey")%>'></asp:Literal><br />
        </p>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_H" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQL_SRC_DEV_GROUPINGDESCS" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="FTE_PARENT_SKEY"></asp:DropDownList><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I now need to get the selectedvalues for each instance of dropdown created, and += to a variable so that I can built a SQL INSERT command based on the selected values.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to achieve this please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the items in the Repeater in code behind and use FindControl to get the SelectedValue of the DropDownList.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //loop all the items in the repeater
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        //use findcontrol to locate the dropdownlist and cast it back to one
        DropDownList drp = item.FindControl("DropDownList_H") as DropDownList;

        //display the result
        Label1.Text += drp.SelectedValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks VDWWD - this looks like exactly what I'm after.  I forgot to mention that my code in in VB - any chance you could show again in VB?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks VDWWD - I have converted to VB and it work perfectly!  Much appreciated.

VB version shown below:

```
Protected Sub GEN_CODE()

    Dim txtField As DropDownList
    Dim DDL_Values As String = ""
    For Each item In Repeater1.Items

        //use findcontrol to locate the dropdownlist and cast it back to one
        txtField = item.FindControl("DropDownList_H")

        //display the result
        DDL_Values += " " + txtField.SelectedValue

    Next

End Sub
```